# Why Java program compiles and runs in IntelliJ but on terminal does not find dependencies?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java project on IntelliJ about language detection. I have used this package: https://github.com/optimaize/language-detector and everything works fine in IntelliJ. Infact the program compiles and runs without any problem.

Sadly when I try to compile it with

> javac Main.java

on terminal it says

> error: package com.optimaize.langdetect does not exist

Mainly I am using my laptop in development, and I would like to run the code on a DigitalOcean server. How can I fix this? 
I have thought about the JAVA environment variables and paths, or the maven dependencies, but they should be taken care of by IntelliJ, right?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: most likely you configured the dependencies in your ide, and not on a global classpath

Comment: make a runnable jar and try again

Comment: @AsierAranbarri how is one supposed to create a runnable jar if it doesn't compile?

Comment: @AsierAranbarri yes, and now he is trying to COMPILE it through the prompt, that's where the error occurs. As the op stated in "Sadly when I try to compile it on terminal it says error: package com.optimaize.langdetect does not exist".
the question is about why it compiles in the IDE and not through the terminal, not about runtime issues.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the full command line you are using to compile. Remember to include the classpath.

Comment: @Stultuske you are right mate.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri well ... it happens :)

Comment: @Stultuske feels like dumb, man. ; )

Comment: Oh, thanks for the quick replies! As a totally beginner about this, how exactly do I make a jar/fix dependencies? :)

Comment: you can't create a jar until after compilation. if you want to be able to compile from the terminal, you need to make sure that it also has access to the dependencies

Comment: @Mazzespazze In order to specify the classpath on terminal run `javac -cp <path>`. The exact notation is platform-dependent (see `javac -help` for help or refer to online help of java compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Compile the jar on your pc, and then run the jar file on the server.

If you want to compile on the server with dependencies, I recommend to use a build system.

Since you are using maven (I think) you should compile with `mvn install` instead of `javac`.